# Recovering Files from 2nd HDD on a Ubuntu Server

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, files, data-recovery, crash

Been Long time, Ok So I have a Ubuntu 12 Server with 2 HDD's 1st HDD is Holding the OS and the 2nd HDD is Holding the Data.  The users suddenly complained that there are no documents in the Share Folder.  When I checked the Whole Folder was missing!! No files. So before trying to finding out who did what I need to recover these files.  I have used photorec but can't seems to get it to recover the data properly.  Any Help is Appreciated Very Much

Comment: is it possible for you to reboot your server with a boot disk? what is the HDD's filesystem?

Comment: ext4.  I am using Ubutu Rescue mix bootable CD

Comment: use this: http://www.active-undelete.com/

http://s12.p30download.com/users/212/software/acc/01/2015/1/Active.UNDELETE.v10.0.39_p30download.com.rar